# PHP : How to create a directory in the server drives

Tags: php

I'm working on a project where I'm creating a agency. While creating agency I'm having a dropdown to select the drive. In that drive a folder will be created with the agency name and in which all the exported data will be stored. I'm able to get all the drives in the server by executing few shell commands. I'm trying to create the folder using the following code :

```
$agency = 'BookStore';
$documentLocation = $val['drive'] . '/agency/documents/document-' . $agency;

if (!is_dir($documentLocation)) {
    var_dump(mkdir($documentLocation, 0777, true));
}
```

where $val['drive'] is the drive path. But it creates the folder inside my project and I want to create the folder in the specified drive.

Comment: What's the exact value of `$documentLocation`…?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the `$documentLocation` it produces? If `$val['drive']` is something like 'C' for example (if you're on Windows) then the path will be invalid (missing a colon 'C:')

Comment: don't forget: `777` is evil. never use it. use the least permissive configuration possible.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is  the `$val['drive']`. If Your OS is Windows, you still need some additional formatting like adding **COLON :** Forward-Slashes wouldn't be a Problem in Windows anymore as in Unix.

```
 <?php

     $agency           = 'BookStore';
     $isWindows        = true; //<== A FUNCTION THAT CHECKS IF IT'S A WINDOWS OS
     $location         = '/agency/documents/document-' . $agency;
     //IF IT'S WINDOWS OS,WE JUST ADD A COLON (:) AFTER THE DRIVE NAME
     $documentLocation = (isWindows)?$val['drive'] .":" . $location : $val['drive']. $location;


    if (!is_dir($documentLocation)) {
        var_dump(mkdir($documentLocation, 0777, true));
    }
```

Comment: If it's *not* Windows you wouldn't need the drive letter at all…

Comment: @deceze         Exactly....but perhaps the `$val['drive']` points to `the Address of the Mounted-Volume` on Linux or OSX but no Longer the **C, D, E, F....AND Z** Drives of the Windows OS..... something like `"/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD"` in Mac or `/home/media/user/ExternalHDD` in Linunx

Comment: @Poiz yes, it is a unix server. so the drives are something like this : /dev/sdb1, /dev/sdb2